# Resizing overlay image

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an overlay image ( consider it as a container image or I can split it to 2 images) and need to put a video inside it ( in the black area ) .
The problem is that I need to make this works for different video sizes which all of them have the same aspect ratio (16:9 video aspect ratio )
These are the video sizes I have :

```
1280 x 720 ( aspect ratio is 16:9 )
1920 x 1080n ( aspect ratio is 16:9 )
2560 x 1440 ( aspect ratio is 16:9 )
```

I have an image overlay to contain these videos, How can I first dynamicly resize this image overlay based on width of input video and then put the video on it ?
since I have different video sizes I cannot say the proper position of video to be overlaid on image , is there any trick like using percentages instead of pixel ?

the height of the top image and bottom image are not the same :

this is the overlay image : https://i.ibb.co/4SCMhqL/sample-overlay.jpg

Comment: The image should stretch according to the video size correct? I think the best strategy would be to take the images apart and then use a combination of the filters scale2ref (allows to set the size of an object based on the size of an refereed object) and vstack (vertically align objects).

Comment: Would that be as expected: https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=8E0E12FBD10DA3C0&resid=8E0E12FBD10DA3C0%2141229&authkey=ANyq_N27xz_H8cw

Comment: @RicardoBohner Thanks for the reply, no it should not stretch. the video container part is somehow that fits the video aspect ratio . 
The video you uploaded seems great, is the command somehow that works for different video sizes ( with the same aspect ratio ) ?

Comment: The video aspect ratio changes because you add the top + bottom to the hight. For example the original video was 1920x1080, final video: 1920 x 1588. Or do you want to overlay the images over the video croping it partly where the images are?

Comment: @RicardoBohner yes the container image aspect ratio is 64 : 53 and it has enough space to contain a 16:9 video in it, so the final video will be 64 : 53 because of the 2 parts we added at top and bottom of the original video .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I used in my tests, please see if it gets you the expected output

**By using 2 images:**

In this example I cut the top and bottom part in 2 separate images:

```
ffmpeg -i Input.mp4 -i Top.jpg -i Bottom.jpg -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w=iw:h=ow/mdar[top][vid];[2][vid]scale2ref=w=iw:h=ow/mdar[bottom][vid];[top][vid][bottom]vstack=inputs=3[final];[final]scale=iw:-2[final]" -map [final] -map 0:a:0 -shortest -vsync 0 -c:v libx264 "Output.mp4"
```

This was the resulting video: [test.mp4](https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=8E0E12FBD10DA3C0&resid=8E0E12FBD10DA3C0%2141229&authkey=ANyq_N27xz_H8cw)

**By using a single image:**

In this example I used the image provided by the topic creator.

Considering the following coordinates:

[image]

In theory at least form my calculations this should have worked perfectly but I still got some black strip between the video and the bottom part but no big mess...

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i img.jpg -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w=iw:h=ow/mdar[img][vid];[vid][img]scale2ref=h=ih*((533-(53+118))/533)[vid][img];[img][vid]overlay=x=0:y=H*((53)/533)[final];[final]scale=iw:-2[final]" -map 0:a:0 -map [final] -shortest -vsync 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Explaining:

```
This part sets the image same width and proportional height as video width:
"[1][0]scale2ref=w=iw:h=ow/mdar[img][vid];
Sets the video height according to the black area:
[vid][img]scale2ref=h=ih*((533-(53+118))/533)[vid][img]
Positions the video as overlay under the top part of the image:
[img][vid]overlay=x=0:y=H*((53)/533)[final]
Scales the resulting video to force the height to be divisible by 2 cause mp4 videos return errors if the height is not divisible by 2...:
[final]scale=iw:-2[final]"
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine. Is it possible to have a buymeacofee link from you so I can ... ?

Comment: I have paypal ricardobohner@yahoo.com.br

Comment: Thats great ! Thanks .

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: No need to split the image. Use scale2ref to rescale the image, then use it as first input in overlay with video as 2nd input.

Comment: @Gyan, but how to put the video exactly in the black area?

Comment: Via co-ordinates, Which you already need to split the src into two images.